How can I build a Template Studio to put my Classes and future like Microsoft Template Studio
Open Visual Studio to Create new Project:
ex: mycompany.template
After that come like this photo to select the needs feature
enter image description here
Create Custom Project with selected feature:

Database Manager
Auth Service
Commands
Services
Dashboard-Layout before creates the Projects.

After creates the Project, find all selected feature in the solution explorer Visual Studio
Template Studio For WPF
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWPF

You need to create your own custom template wizard implementation.
Check out this awnser.
In order to create optional files based on the users input i would create a base project template with all the mandatory files, and then i would create an item template with the indidual optional files. Here is an example.
If you have any questions feel free to ask.

I created a Project Template and added two features to them.
Created VSIX Project an add to it "Wizard Implementation" class + TemplateWizerdPage, but I don't know how I can select one of the two features to be generated in the Created Project

You are going to need to create your own wizard that allows users to select the features, then you can load the selected features. https://library.tebyan.net/fa/Viewer/Read/164891/72 - Here you can see how the features could be loaded.
